# 15 month old wakes up crying at night and wont sleep again without me

Tags: toddler, sleep

My 15mo used to sleep all night ,until a month ago.He now wakes up at night crying and standing on his feet and wont sleep until i lay with him and sleep together. How do I stop this from happening?

It is not teething (tried given him medicine but still woke up after 2 hours). He usually eats a snack around 19.00 and drinks a bottle around 20.00 and goes to sleep at 21.00.

There is white noise and a little light, I've also tried no light but he still wakes up. His diaper is clean and temperature is 70 degrees fahreneit .

This is happening every night , approximately 3 hours after he falls asleep. When he starts crying his eyes are open , i dont think it is nightmares .He was sleeptrained (pickup put down method) and knew how to selfsooth with a pacifier. When he starts crying , I pick him and hold him and he seems to fall asleep instantly but the minute I try to put him back in his crib ,starts crying again.i put a matress on the floor and lay down with him , and he stays asleep when when I am there with him. But he continues to try and find me in his sleep, wants to hold me or sleep on top of me.

Comment: Hi Yio, welcome to our site. Have you read all the Related questions in the sidebar? This is very common, so one of them will surely help you.

Comment: Is he having nightmares?

Comment: We need more info here. Are they asking for something in particular? Are their needs met? (diaper, drink, food)? Is the room conducive to sleep? (dryness, temperature, sound, light) Do they exhibit this same behavior whenever they go to bed, or only if they wake up abruptly?

Comment: What's his bedtime routine? does he fall asleep on his own when you put him to bed for bedtime?

Comment: He usually drinks milk ,then we play for a while. After a while I lower the lights and switch on a little night light. We go to the bathroom to wash and brush teeth or bathe him, come back to the room put on jamies, switch on white noise .
I hold him for a minute or two singing a song,put him in his crib . He usually is sleepy but awake and it takes him a while(between 5 to 20 minutes) to settle and sleep on his own.

Answer (score 0):

> i put a matress on the floor and lay down with him , and he stays
> asleep when when I am there with him. But he continues to try and find
> me in his sleep, wants to hold me or sleep on top of me.

I think he's just discovered that he likes this better than sleeping alone.  But if it's not what you want, then you'll need to end the habit.  There probably is not a pain-free way to do this, but you sleep trained him once, he can learn again.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, it sounds like he wishes to be near you at night. It sounds like waking up alone terrifies him.

Given that he's only 15 months old, that's understandable. All his other needs may be met – and it sounds like you've made sure of that – but if his biggest one, human contact, is not, then I suggest being there for him.

The fact that merely putting him back in his crib causes him to cry *while he's awake* means it's not an issue with his sleep. No amount of 'training' will change his desire to be with you. (Not to mention that humans cannot be trained like dogs.) Wanting to be around a trusted person like one's parent, especially when small and defenseless against a world that can be big and scary (and dark, at night!), is healthy and normal.

Is there any reason not to sleep in the same room from the get go? It sounds like this would both soothe him and prevent you from being woken up by his crying. He needs to know that you will be there for him whenever he needs you – once he understands that, he will know he has nothing to fear when he's alone, and his crying should subside.